# How to properly set IDs on Angular components' input elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to think of the best way to address this situation. I have an angular component that builds a card with information on a employee which you can edit, I have checkboxes, text fields, etc.

This component is built multiple times on a single page, one instance of the component for each employee registered. I'm having conflicts with the `id` attribute of the `checkbox` inputs; since the component is built multiple times, when I click on the checkbox on the second card, the box that is checked is actually the one on the first card.

This is the structure that I have on the component template.

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.readonly]="editAgentState ? null : 'readonly'" checked id="card-weekday-mon" class="weekday"
                />
                <label for="card-weekday-mon">Mo</label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked id="card-weekday-tue" class="weekday" />
                <label for="card-weekday-tue">Th</label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked id="card-weekday-wed" class="weekday" />
                <label for="card-weekday-wed">We</label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked id="card-weekday-thu" class="weekday" />
                <label for="card-weekday-thu">Tu</label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked id="card-weekday-fri" class="weekday" />
                <label for="card-weekday-fri">Fr</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="card-weekday-sat" class="weekday" />
                <label for="card-weekday-sat">Sa</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="card-weekday-sun" class="weekday" />
                <label for="card-weekday-sun">Su</label>
              </div>
```

So I'm trying to find what would be the best way to kinda set a dynamic `Id` for each checkbox, so that the click affects the exact checkbox that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable from your ts file as your id for the div like

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.readonly]="editAgentState ? null : 'readonly'" checked id={{employee.name}} class="weekday"/>
```

And you could populate employee name from your ts file. This way every instance of your component will have separate ids.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can generate a random ID for you input and label HTML tags in each component instance (ngOnInit), but you can set it with any other variable you have in your TS file.

In TS file:

```
id: string = 'id';

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.idGenerator();
}

idGenerator(): void {
   this.id += Math.random().toString().slice(2);
}
```

In HTML file:

```
<input [id]="id" />
<label [for]="id">Label Text</label>
```